# PHP - MySQL data is html code and php doesn't show correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have some values in my database which a column named `description` contains HTML CODE ex. (`<p>&nbsp;</p><div class="col-xs-8">..`).

I get the database rows and try to show it in the page, all the columns displays normal (as it is plain text) BUT when I `echo` the variable that contains `description` value it doesn't turn the code into "page", it only shows the code.

Where is the problem? Shouldn't it consider as code as well and add it to the page?

CODE:

```
<div class="info">
   <div class="info-space" style="width: 800px;"></div>
        <?php
            echo $pro_desc;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the result of this: `var_dump($pro_desc);`?

Comment: The database is holding a string, not markup. You have to store it in such a way so as to return the markup.

Comment: when you view the html source that your php page echoed, (ctrl+u) what does the html look like?

Comment: @RightClick it shows with a double quote in the beginning `"<p>&nbsp;</p><div class="col-xs-8">...`

Comment: @tuananh result of var_dump: `string '&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;col-xs-8&quot;...length(25000)`

Comment: @JayBlanchard and what way would that be? Could you orientate me?

Comment: q: why do you have HTML in your db? why not just do that in your PHP? it's just more work / pain for nothing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- , some developers give their users wysiwyg editors.  it's not structured data...and saving the html in one field is a valid approach imho

Comment: @Fred-ii- because, my client makes hes own "table-designs" or "product-info-design". Different product, different info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$pro_desc` looks like this:

```
string '&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;col-xs-8&quot;...length(25000)
```

In order to display it correctly, you need to convert it to HTML format, for example `&lt;p&gt;` to `<p>` and so on. Try this:

```
echo "<p>".html_entity_decode($pro_desc)."</p>";
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: So, it worked as I expected. (I have had read about it before). BUT is there any other option to make it work? As in, doing something in the database?

Comment: Why would you need another option @holpducki?

Comment: @JayBlanchard so I can have it configured in the database and not in my PHP/HTML files.

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct as it fixed my problem. But im still looking for anther option of fixing it. Thank you

Comment: there is *no other option* @holpducki

Comment: @JayBlanchard there is no database/column configuration in MySQL that instead of using a PHP function I can just config it?

Comment: I'm afraid not @holpducki

Answer (score 0):

It's important that you try this code:

```
htmlspecialchars($_POST['description'] , ENT_QUOTES);
```

before you save your description in the database and when you need to fetch this field use :

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($data['description']);
```

You can read more here. http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: Do you have another option? As in configuring the database column?

Comment: I used that before and I implement this code 
[Html_Page] [nvarchar](max) NULL, in sqlserver. In Mysql you need to use a Text field. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html